# Swiftui + Firebase project with overflowing memory

Tags: firebase, swiftui, firebase-storage

I'm working on a social media type of app that uses firebase for backend but I am running into this issue where for each post cell that is being loaded the memory progressively gets higher to a point where its unusable. My post struct in firebase contains a link to an image in storage and a few other fields which are loaded when displayed but they don't disappear so thats the issue. I was wondering if there was a way to have a scrolling view that unloads previous posts or if there is any workaround to this issue otherwise. Please let me know if you want a code snippit. Thanks!

I've tried clearing the post array on disappear to see if the memory could be freed when the view is switched but that didnt work the posts were still loaded just waiting to be populated in the array which is populated when the feed appears.

```
struct FeedView: View {
    @StateObject var viewModel = FeedViewModel()
    @State var feedType: FeedType = FeedType.following
    @State var isEmpty: Bool = false
    @State var color: String
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            ScrollView {
                if((viewModel.posts.isEmpty || viewModel.isEmpty) && feedType == FeedType.following) {
                    Image(systemName: "person.2.slash")
                        .resizable()
                        .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                        .cornerRadius(20.0)
                        .frame(width: 200, height: 200)
                        .foregroundColor(Color.init(hex: color))
                        .padding(.top, 100)
                    Text(viewModel.isEmpty ? "You aren't following any other users..." :"The users your following have no outfits...")
                        .font(.subheadline)
                        .foregroundColor(Color(.systemGray))
                    Text(viewModel.isEmpty ? "Click over a tab to find friends!" : "Check out whats Hot!")
                        .font(.subheadline)
                        .foregroundColor(Color(.systemGray))
                    
                } else {
                    LazyVStack(spacing: 32) {
                        ForEach(viewModel.posts) { post in
                            PostCell(viewModel: PostCellViewModel(post: post), isProfile: false)//, color: color)
                        }
                    }
                    .padding(.top)
                }
            }
            .toolbar(content: {
                ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarLeading) {
                    Image("logon")
                        .resizable()
                        .frame(width: 40, height: 40)
                        .padding(.bottom, 40)
                        .padding(.trailing, 20)
                        .padding(.top, 20)
                }
        
                ToolbarItem(placement: .navigation) {
                    Button {
                        feedType = FeedType.following
                        Task{ try await viewModel.fetchPostsFromFollowedUsers() }
                    } label: {
                        Text("Following")
                            .font(.callout)
                            .fontWeight(.semibold)
                            .foregroundColor(feedType == FeedType.following ? Color.init(hex: color) : Color(.systemGray))
                    }
                }
                
                ToolbarItem(placement: .navigation) {
                    Button {
                        feedType = FeedType.hot
                        Task{ try await viewModel.fetchAllPosts() }
                    } label: {
                        Text("Hot")
                            .font(.callout)
                            .fontWeight(.semibold)
                            .foregroundColor(feedType == FeedType.hot ? Color.init(hex: color) : Color(.systemGray))
                    }
                }
                
                ToolbarItem(placement: .navigation) {
                    Button {
                        feedType = FeedType.creator
                        Task { try await viewModel.fetchCreatorPosts() }
                    } label: {
                        Text("Creators")
                            .font(.callout)
                            .fontWeight(.semibold)
                            .foregroundColor(feedType == FeedType.creator ? Color.init(hex: color) : Color(.systemGray))
                    }
                }
            })
            .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)
            .refreshable {
                Task {
                    switch(feedType) {
                    case(.following) :
                        Task { try await viewModel.fetchPostsFromFollowedUsers() }
                    case(.hot) :
                        Task { try await viewModel.fetchAllPosts() }
                    case(.creator) :
                        Task { try await viewModel.fetchCreatorPosts() }
                    }
                }
            }
            .navigationDestination(for: User.self) { user in
                ProfileView(user: user)
                    .navigationBarBackButtonHidden(true)
            }
            .navigationDestination(for: Post.self) { post in
                PostCell(viewModel: PostCellViewModel(post: post), isProfile: true)//, color: "")
                    .navigationBarBackButtonHidden(true)
            }
            .navigationDestination(for: SearchViewModelConfig.self) { config in
                ListView(config: config, color: .blue)
                    .navigationBarBackButtonHidden(true)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You aren't showing any code, so it's impossible to know what strategy you're currently employing, but `LazyVStack` will only load views on screen (and slightly off screen)

Comment: Use a list for such type of view.

Comment: A lazyvstack is being used and it’s only loading views on screen but the issue is that once loaded they take up too much memory

Comment: @devdchaudhary why would a list be beneficial here? Would it only load displayed cells?

Comment: @TylerGeorge exactly. that's how a list works, it only renders what is to be displayed on the screen.

Comment: @devdchaudhary when trying to implement a list I just get a blank screen do you know if there is away to unload lazyVStack items, I like how the lazyVStack doesnt load everything at once.

Comment: Are you putting your list inside the scrollview?